# A jQuery plugin to do multiple things to a single jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I find myself doing different things to the same jQuery object a lot.
So instead of doing something like this:

```
var thing = $("pile_o_selectors");
thing.blah;
thing.blah_2;
//...
thing.blah_n;
```

or even worse

```
$("selectors").blah;
$("selectors").blah_2;
//...
$("selectors").blah_n;
```

So, I made a little jQuery plugin to let me do this:

```
$("selectors").do(function(){
  this.blah;
  this.blah_2;
  this.blah_n;
});
```

Is there a built in jQuery function that already does this? Or even a plugin that already exists and is tested and mature so I don't have to put effort into making sure mine works in all cases? I tried searching the web a bit, but I don't even know what to call it.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the different "things" you're doing with the same jQuery object?

Comment: You appear to be describing the characteristics of a JavaScript `function`. A jQuery plugin is OTT unless you need method chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what those 'things' you want to do are, but can they simply be chained?

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp

```
i.e. $("#p1").css("color","red").slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need. I had no idea I could do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just chain them. For example:

```
$('selector')
    .hide()
    .text("Hello, world!")
    .fadeIn();
```

This works for most methods that have nothing obvious to return; in that case, they return the jQuery object again, making it possible. However, if they need to return something, then they can't return the jQuery object, and you cannot chain any further.